# How can I capture an element using a Regex in Nunit?

Tags: regex, nunit, webdriver, specflow

I want to capture something similar to the following

```
IWebElement commentField = Regex.Match(driver.PageSource,"TextBoxComments$",RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Where the TextBox has a variable that is updated each time the page is loaded, but since the page element always ends with TextBoxComments I can use that as a capture key.  I want to then use this in an NUnit/SpecFlow test to then add a comment to the page, it worked in a test page but now that the element is more variable my test is failing.  I'm not sure what's the best way to capture this element and then be able to perform an opertation on it.  Is there a better capture method or do I need to convert the Regex capture element somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can do this...my eventual solution:

> IWebElement commentField =
>   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("*[id*='TextBoxComments']"));

Just needed to use the right CssSelector and regex to get my match.